Erase and write operations not working on DSPIC33EP512MU814
I've been trying to write some data to a fixed location on DSPIC33EP512MU814 microcontroller. Despite multiple attempts, I am unable to see any success.
I referred reference manual DS70609. Followed the exact steps, but still I couldn't see any change in the flash memory. First I tried to implement it manually and also tried with some examples from various forums. I am using ICD3 debugger to flash and debug the code. I'll share my implementation
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF, WDTPOST = PS256, WDTPRE = PR128, WINDIS = OFF
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC, IESO = ON
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF, ICS = PGD2
#pragma config GWRP = OFF, GSS = OFF, GSSK = OFF
#pragma config FPWRT = PWR128, BOREN = ON
#pragma config RSTPRI = PF, AWRP = OFF, APL = OFF, APLK = OFF
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD, OSCIOFNC = OFF, POSCMD = XT


uint16 TestData1 = 0x1234;
uint16 TestData2 = 0x5678;
uint16 TestData3 = 0xABCD;

uint16 TestData4 = 0xEFAB;

static void FlashErase(uint32 address)
{
    
  NVMADR = address;           // Load the address to erase
  NVMADRU = (address >> 16);  // Load the upper bits of the address 
  NVMCON = 0x4003;
   NVMKEY = 0x55;
   NVMKEY = 0xAA;
   NVMCONbits.WR = 1;
   __builtin_nop();
   __builtin_nop();
   while (NVMCONbits.WR);      // Wait for erase to complete

    // Check for errors
   if (NVMCONbits.WRERR) 
   {
        // Handle erase error
   }
}

static void FlashWrite(uint32 address)
{
  NVMADR = address;           // Load the address to erase
  NVMADRU = (address >> 16);  // Load the upper bits of the address 
  NVMCON = 0x4001;
  TBLPAG = 0xFA;
  
__builtin_tblwtl(0, TestData1);
__builtin_tblwth(0, TestData2);
__builtin_tblwtl(2, TestData3);
__builtin_tblwth(2, TestData4);

   NVMKEY = 0x55;
   NVMKEY = 0xAA;
   NVMCONbits.WR = 1;
   __builtin_nop();
   __builtin_nop();
   while (NVMCONbits.WR);      // Wait for erase to complete

    // Check for errors
   if (NVMCONbits.WRERR) 
   {
        // Handle erase error
   }

}


The address I am trying to erase is 0x1EE00. From the debugger (ICD3), after stepping over the function, I couldn't see any change in program memory. It is intact. Am I doing something wrong here? Do I need to change any configuration bits to do any unlock procedure?

Hi, problem solved. Infact the erase operation was working. The debugger was not showing live data update of the flash memory during debug session. When I tried to read the memory manually, I could see the erasure is taking place.
